# Call a Python class function from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I am working on my first web application. and I meet a problem that is how I can call a pyhton class funtion from jquery.
for exmaple:

Server:

I applied SQLAlchemy to build a model class named `user`, which contains two data members: `id` and `name` and one function `changename(new_name)`, then I created some of instances of the `user` class and stored them into a list named `origin_list`.

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html', member_list=origin_list)
    # origin_list is a list that contains the objects of user class
```

HTML+JS: There is button with a script file:

```
script type="text/javascript" 
var name = "123"
{{member_list[0].change_name(name)}} 
// is this possible? cause I can print user id and name by {{member_list[some_index].id}} and {{member_list[some_index].name}}
// if this a not ok, is there anyway can let me change the name and store in the origin_list script
```

Comment: You are not thinking about the problem in a RESTful way. You need to expose endpoints on your server to make every change you need to the database. Then you can call those endpoints with JQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Probably could use the frame work you are in.  Jquery has no visibility into the framework so you can't do that directly.  What you can do is post to the framework, and have the framework return a js script that it runs on the page itself. I do this with uploading bars when they upload a file.  The post sends the file to a function, and the function returns a script that turn off the loading bar and returns the file name.